# How to replace polenta in Mexican Polenta Casserole recipe

Tags: substitutions

The recipe asks for one 16 oz. package of precooked polenta, but I only have yellow corn grits (uncooked, [from Bob's Red Mill](http://www.bobsredmill.com/gluten-free-corn-grits-polenta.html) - also labeled as polenta). How much do I cook for it to be equivalent?

Comment: Is the recipe looking for the fairly firm kind, maybe to slice or crumble?

Comment: Is this "precooked polenta" a meal... that is instant polenta that doesn't require long cooking; or is it a ready-to-eat product of some kind?

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ I'm fairly certain it's ready-to-eat, the kind of thing you get with an image search for "precooked polenta" (I've seen it in plenty of stores): http://foodpractice.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/DSC_6256.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Corn grits are not the best possible substitute for polenta:

- Polenta is the Italian name for corn meal
- Instant polenta is basically polenta that has been cooked, then dried and ground; it is precooked, and and pre-gelatinized, and so does not require long cooking
- Precooked polenta is available, in a tube or tub, which is literally a prepared, cooked polenta.
- Grits are a ground corn product, where the corn has been treated with lye (it is made from hominy)

A better substitute for uncooked polenta would be plain corn meal (1:1); for precooked polenta would be cornmeal that has been cooked into a thick porridge (1:1).

If you do substitute hominy type grits for plain polenta, your result will be somewhat different, but you can try 1:1, by volume or weight, either way.

Update:  evidently some processors label their product "Grits" as well as "Traditional Italian Polenta".  While I cannot endorese misusing the word grits, in this case, then, they are the same product so it isn't really a substitution, and 1:1 is the proper use.

Comment: There are plenty of grits available that *aren't* made from hominy. I think the OP's are one of them: http://www.bobsredmill.com/corn-grits_polenta.html (but I've seen this kind of labeling from even generic store brands).

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ The corner of the label says "traditional italian polenta. The middle of the label says "Polenta. Corn Grits." And the back has a recipe for "Basic Italian Polenta."

Comment: @jefromi If that is the case... wow.  It would consider it poor labelling since the hominy thing is essential to what grits *are*.

Comment: @marke Then your answer is 1:1.

Comment: Updated based on all this information.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ But a 16 ounce package of precooked polenta contains water weight, so 16 ounces of the dried product I have would end up weighting more right? So I would have to use less of mine to end up with 16 ounces (which I find difficult to approximate/measure), correct? I'm probably wrong as I have no idea what precooked polenta is.

Comment: You would cook the grits (polenta), and substitute the *cooked* products 1:1.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ I interpreted the original question as implicitly including the question of "what's the ratio between weights of dry and cooked polenta". (Fortunately this is just for a casserole, so exact quantities aren't that important.)

Comment: @jefromi Cooked polenta can range from a thin gruel to a quite substantial slab that can be sliced and even fried; it isn't possible to really answer that, definitively.    By volume, 3:1 (water to polenta) would be fairly thick; 4:1 is common.